# Java script how to pass around an object with event being attached

Tags: javascript

I have a custom object that being passed around. I want to show a toast when a workflow is done. 
I am looking for some thing like

```
object.addEvent("workflowIsDone", ()=> {
    toast.open();
});
```

and when the workflow ends:

```
object.fireEvent("workFlowIsDone")
```

I was wondering if some one can tell me how to do it in Javascript

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Keep an `event name -> array of functions` mapping around. Have `addEvent` add the argument to the right array. Have `fireEvent` iterate over the corresponding array and call each element.

Answer (score 1):

You might add a method to your object:

```
object.workflowIsDone = () => toast.open();
```

and call it when the workflow ends:

```
object.workFlowIsDone()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can produce new events by using `const myEvent = new Event('eventName')`

And then add a listener to it:
`element.addEventListener('eventName', function () { // ... })`

Also you need to dispatch it:
`element.dispatchEvent(myEvent)`

For passing custom data there's a `CustomEvent` class that you can use. You can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events)